# Koa-better-body file uploading not working

Tags: koa2, koa-router

I'm using Koa-better-body with Koa2, and I want to handle single file uploads in a POST form submission (input type=file).

While all the other fields show up properly under ctx.request.fields, i.e. `ctx.request.fields.title`, my file input's contents simply aren't available!

Interestingly,under ctx.request.fields, I still get a *value* for my file input (`ctx.request.fields.coverimage`), but that only gives me a file-name string, not the actual file (a cover image in this case).

What am I missing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet that you forgot to add to your form:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: This was it! Thanks :)

I wanted to find out more, and these were good:
- https://dev.to/sidthesloth92/understanding-html-form-encoding-url-encoded-and-multipart-forms-3lpa

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean